I2S Interface between Bluetooth Module and CODEC
I need to interface my CYBT-343026-01 bluetooth module to the AK4619 CODEC via I2S interface.
The problem is that CYBT-343026-01 only provides BICK and LRCLK, but it doen't provide MCLK which is also required by the CODEC. I can't provide the system clock used by CYBT-343026-01 module, because it is internally generated and can't be output.
I thought to three possible solutions, but I'm not sure they will work;

generate an external separated clock source to give as MCLK to the CODEC. It will be independent from the system clock of the bluetooth module, could this be a problem?

change CODEC and choose one with internal MCLK. Do exist CODECs able to derive their own MCLK from the provided BICK or LRCLK?

use BICK also as MCLK for the CODEC.


Solution number 3) arises because reading the AK4619 datasheet it seems that MCLK can be  be equal to BICK if specific settings are done (look at the following piece of datasheet).

Maybe I can set fs to be BICK/256, so BICK = MCLK, is this possible?
Any other idea is welcome.
